# Reduce SYS_ADMIN Linux capabilities

Tags: docker, containers, linux-capabilities

I am creating a Docker container for which I do not wan to keep 'privileged' flag true. This is in attempt to keep it more secure and for better control. 
My container mainly engaged in following tasks (this will help me define it's resource access scope and enforce access control accordingly)
1. Mount gluster file sys on container
2. Run SSH daemon to accept incoming SSH connections
3. Run some typically available bash commands

I used "--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN" option while running docker container to achieve this. However as SYS_ADMIN adds lot more privileges (listed below) than what I need. How can I achieve only subset of SYS_ADMIN capabilities?

**SYS_ADMIN:**

Perform a range of system administration operations including:       quotactl(2), mount(2), umount(2), swapon(2), swapoff(2),       sethostname(2), and setdomainname(2).

- perform privileged syslog(2)
- operations (since Linux 2.6.37, CAP_SYSLOG should be used to permit
  such operations). perform VM86_REQUEST_IRQ vm86(2) command;
- performIPC_SET and IPC_RMID operations on arbitrary System V IPC
  objects
- perform operations on trusted and security Extended Attributes (see
  attr(5))
- use lookup_dcookie(2).
- use ioprio_set(2) to assign
- IOPRIO_CLASS_RT and (before Linux 2.6.25) IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE I/O
  scheduling classes.
- forge UID when passing socket credentials.
- exceed /proc/sys/fs/file-max, the system-wide limit on the number of
  open    files, in system calls that open files (e.g., accept(2),
  execve(2),    open(2), pipe(2)).
- employ CLONE_* flags that create new namespaces    with clone(2) and
  unshare(2).
- call perf_event_open(2).
- access privileged perf event information.
- call setns(2).
- call fanotify_init(2).
- perform KEYCTL_CHOWN and KEYCTL_SETPERM keyctl(2)    operations.
- perform madvise(2) MADV_HWPOISON operation.
- employ the    TIOCSTI ioctl(2) to insert characters into the input
  queue of a    terminal other than the caller's controlling terminal.
  employ the    obsolete nfsservctl(2) system call.
- employ the obsolete bdflush(2)    system call.
- perform various privileged block-device ioctl(2)    operations.
- perform various privileged file-system ioctl(2)    operations.
- perform administrative operations on many device drivers.

Comment: None of the other capabilities would be enough? (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/729c9a97822ebee2c978a322d37060454af6bc66/vendor/src/github.com/syndtr/gocapability/capability/enum_gen.go) Like net_admin, to mount file system?